# Too many login attempts

Tags: plugins, login, security

Since a week or two I keep receiving the following automatic email message sent from my WordPress website, and I'd like to know if it indicates any security hole and if there's anything I can do to stop it :

"A host, 79.148.238.85(you can check the host at http://ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/79.148.238.85) has been locked out of the WordPress site at http://my_site.com until Friday, February 22nd, 2013 at 9:41:54 am UTC due to too many login attempts. You may login to the site to manually release the lock if necessary."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the plugin `Better WP Security`

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/

installed with the `Enable login limits` feature activated here `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=better-wp-security-loginlimits`. You can configure the plugin to stop sending you these messages. But you should have the feature activated, since most likely some **bot** is trying to login. Or even consider to blacklist this IP in the plugin via the `Ban` page in `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=better-wp-security-banusers` (if you are sure this is not an actual user in your Wordpress trying to login)

ps: I get these messages a lot and on some installs I use the `htpasswd` to stop the bots from accessing the wp-login page ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like [SI CAPTCHA](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/) which adds a captcha to your login page and this will prevent bots from using brute force attacks on your Wordpress.